# Setting per-folder values for suhosin settings in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, php

I've set suhosin.perdir = 'p' in my ini file. I would now like to change suhosin ini settings on a per-folder basis.

The following all work (running phpinfo() inside the desired folder shows the changed values):

```
php_value suhosin.post.max_array_depth 100
php_value suhosin.post.max_array_index_length 128
php_value suhosin.post.max_name_length 128
php_value suhosin.post.max_value_length 2000000
php_value suhosin.post.max_totalname_length 512
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 1000
```

But when I also add the .request settings (which I understand are an upper limit for the .post settings), they do not change:

```
php_value suhosin.request.max_array_depth 100
php_value suhosin.request.max_array_index_length 128
php_value suhosin.request.max_name_length 128
php_value suhosin.request.max_value_length  2000000
php_value suhosin.request.max_totalname_length 512
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 1000
```

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Hq6kIKiFvTM/T8NgzIZUafI/AAAAAAAAADY/EPKx_bJ9YLg/s400/1338204362948.png

Do you have any idea if there is anything else I have to check/setup? Am I forgetting someting?

Thank you!
Matei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set suhosin.perdir = 'pr' for it to read both request and post values from an .htaccess file I think.. Don't have anything to test this on currently though.